# Python: How to change the URL for a page on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, url, url-routing

I have a website that I am trying to change the url of a specific page. 
It is an "insights" page for the website, and as it stands, the url is something like this: www.websitename.com/en/insights

However, I would like to change the page name to: www.websotename.com/en/insights/about-this-company

I am using python but very very new to it. I imagine I would need to write some code in the build file.

This is the section of the code that builds the page I believe:

```
prod = False
pages = ['homepage', 'solutions', 'work','insights']
srcLoc = 'src'
assetsLoc = 'assets'
buildLoc = 'dist/build'
```

I inherited this code, I didn't write it so sorry if I'm not being clear. I can post most sections of the python file if needed. I've attached a screen shot of my file structure if that helps, and I'm working in the build.py file now, as I believe this is where I could change the url.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance. 
[image]

EDIT: 
This is everything imported into by build.py file, if this is helpful:

```
import logging as log
import json, string
from pprint import pprint
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import os,sys,shutil
from scss import Compiler
from css_html_js_minify import process_single_html_file, process_single_js_file, process_single_css_file, html_minify, js_minify, css_minify
```

Comment: Do this using URL rewriting in the webserver configuration.

Comment: You don't tell us anything useful here. Are you using something like pybuilder? why do you have a build.py file? are you using flask/django? (if not, then why?) I prefer Quart for building web based applications. If you can tell us what web framework you are using thn I can tell you how to change the url..

Comment: Do you know which framework you're using for this site? Usually for these kinds of sites, you can adjust the URL of your page by renaming the files or adding a new folder (ie. to create the page `example.com/path1/path2/`, you would create an index.html file in the path `src/path1/path2`). More details [at the Pelican project docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/content.html#linking-to-internal-content).

Comment: @CarolNg, "These kinds of sites" ?? You already stated  we don't know what framework the OP is using, and so it most definitely would not be a case of creating a directory structure, that is for plain old HTML pages that serve from a directory (note the same structure of directories in websites), The OP will most likely have to edit the code and change a url routing.

Comment: @JackHerer sorry, I am using PyBuilder, which is why I have a build.py file

Comment: @KatherineMichelle what web framework are you using? django/Flask etc?

Comment: @JackHerer sorry, I don't know. How can I find that out? I updated everything that is imported into my build.py file. Otherwise, the rest of the files are just is simple html, css and javascript, and I've attached an image of m file structure if that helps

Comment: @CarolNg How can I find out what framework is being used?

Comment: Ok I don't think you are using a web framework, is the site just basically written in HTML and CSS and JS? If so then it will be a case of using a .htaccess file wit your web server to achieve this. There will many other methods to get this done but I would suggest using htaccess file. I have to wonder why you are using pybuilder for a standard HTML website, I think it must be using python somehow (except pybuilder). How did you come to this point and not know anything about what you are doing?

Comment: @JackHerer I work for a company and my coworker who originally set up this website is on holiday. I built it with html, css and javascript and to upload it to our server he used python, which I am not sure why as I am brand new here. I do know what I am doing, I'm not a total idiot I'm just a beginner and asked for help.

Comment: @KatherineMichelle Sorry I didn't mean to imply anything by what I said. I am struggling to understand the specific ways your collegue has done things, but your issue willbe solved by either using an .htaccess file for url rewriting or change the directory structure names to match what you need and refactor HTML code to change all href's that point to /insights

Comment: My bad, from the imports in your build file, it doesn't look like you're using framework (most of the packages in build.py look like standard python packages). From the snippets you posted, it looks like build.py could be copying the entire file tree from `srcLoc` to `buildLoc`, then compiling the css files in there, but check the main function (there should be something like `name == __main__`) to see if that's really the case. If so, I'm almost certain you can add the folder or change the html file name to change the link.